# jsplumb drag and drop connections are going to the wrong element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I have 2 (or more) draggable divs with a left side and a right side. I want to be able to drag a connection from the right side of the div to the left side of another div. However when I try to do that the connection appears to be working up until I drop the connection. Once I've dropped the connection it draws the connection to itself.

How it currently is working:

[image: Connection drawn to itself]

How I would like it to work:

[image: Connection right before I drop]

My attempt:

```
$(".box").draggable();
var startpointOptions = { isSource:true };
var startpoint = jsPlumb.addEndpoint($('.rBox'), startpointOptions);
var endpointOptions = { isTarget:true };
var endpoint = jsPlumb.addEndpoint($('.lBox'), endpointOptions);
```

Here is my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/99RwZ/1/

**EDIT:** Pruthvi Bharadwaj got it: http://jsfiddle.net/99RwZ/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the parent of the endpoints are different you cannot connect endpoint. place your entire code in a container 'div':

```
<div id="containerId">  //container DIV
    <div class='box'>
        <div class='lBox'></div>
    <div class='rBox'></div>
</div>
<div class='box' style="left:500px">
    <div class='lBox'></div>
    <div class='rBox'></div>
</div>
```

Now while creating endpoints add the option 'container' to specify the scope of endpoint:

```
var startpointOptions = { isSource:true,container:$('#containerId') };
var endpointOptions = { isTarget:true,container:$('#containerId') };
```

Now you will be able to connect them since the endpoints container has been changed to "containerId" div instead of their own parent div's.

For more info regarding where the jsPlumb elements are placed go through the [Document](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/home#container).

If you want the endpoints to move along your DIV then you can make use of

```
jsPlumb.draggable($('.box'));
```

In your case I would suggest extending the jQuery draggable as given below:

```
$('.box').draggable({
    drag:function(){
        jsPlumb.repaint($('.lBox , .rBox', $(this))); // or simply jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
    }
});
```

Comment: This may be why the bug is happening but doesn't actually help. This makes the endpoints connect to each other but not travel with the boxes. See: http://jsfiddle.net/99RwZ/3/

Comment: that got it, added the final jsFiddle to my question